# Versioning in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, versioning, planning, reconcile

Are we planning to have in QGIS implementation of Versioning like Esri?

There is a general need for the the implementation where QGIS is used for planning and planned design in utility can be cancelled. So in a given area two user can plan and edit the existing features. If one job is cancelled, then edits don't be that job is cancelled.

Both users don't see each other work until finalised.

Answer (score 3):

Geogig (http://geogig.org/) can do geospatial data versioning. If different users modify the same feature, it can get tricky, but merging and versioning distributed editing is easy. Geogig works on shapefiles, postGIS databases, and a few other data formats. They're working on a QGIS plugin, but I haven't seen any updates on that in a few months.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [www.merginmaps.com](http://www.merginmaps.com)
The service is based on geodiff (https://github.com/MerginMaps/geodiff) which allows you to version the data down to changes to a field of a feature.

https://merginmaps.com/docs/manage/project-details/
[image: QGIS project history on Mergin Maps web]

It is very different from git, as you can only see the latest version of data and there is no approval built in the system.

In QGIS, you can run Mergin Maps plugin which allows you to synchronise the data and also extract changelog between two versions:
https://merginmaps.com/docs/manage/plugin-sync-project/#extract-local-changes-processing-toolbox

Disclaimer: I work for Mergin Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FastVersion/

Is a Qgis plugin that integrates with Postgres-Postgis database and allows versioning, user security administration and project management.

I was trained 18 years ago on SmallWorld GIS.
At that time Smallworld had a database technology with versioning capability called VMDS (Version Managed Data Store) and was unique at that time.
Versioning, allows multiple revisions of the data without duplicating all the data, or requiring different databases to be created.
 As data Versioning showed to be very important, other vendors like ESRI-Arcgis implemented their own versioning system, with some similarities and differences.
But to be concise:
The concept of Version is analogous to the concept that has of drawing in a plane of paper. The creation of a version is analogous to the process of making a photocopy of the parent version. But once the photocopy is created the modifications in the original are NOT transferred to the copy and vice versa.
The only way to transfer the changes between two different versions, is through the "POST" function.
In the case of SmallWorld, it also has a “MERGE” function to transfer the changes between two different versions.